# How to get the text "Submit" from below code

Tags: javascript

How to get the text "Submit" from below code. The div dosent have any id

```
      <div class="modal-footer" style="display: block;">
      <button class="psc-cancel btn-gray" data-target="#psc-service-form-modal" data-             dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      <button class="psc-submit btn" data-target="#psc-service-form-modal">Submit</button>
       </div>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('psc-submit btn')[0];
if(button.innerHTML == "Submit") {
   alert('button contains "Submit"');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want pure javascript, try this

```
var submittxt = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[1].textContent;
alert(submittxt);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQVR8/

Answer (score 0):

As the button doesn't have an `id` or `name` attribute, there is no "definite" way to get exactly that button. If it's the only one with that specific `name` attribute, or the only one with the `psc-submit` class, you could query it like this, for example:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('.modal-footer .psc-submit');
```